# Is there a way to prevent the hide operation of a toolbar?

Tags: c++, qt, qtoolbar

In Qt, if I right-click on a toolbar the menu will be shown that allows me to hide the toolbar. I need to disable this functionality because I don't want the toolbar to possible to hide. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inherit QToolbar and reimplement `contextMenuEvent()`.

Comment: Just to contribute with the answer (5 years later): you can avoid the inheritance by installing a filter event, and retaining the event (return true): http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/eventsandfilters.html#event-filters

Comment: This answer would really benefit from an example.

Answer (score 36):

I was able to set the ContextMenuPolicy directly on the *toolbar* (not the main window), as long as I used either `Qt::PreventContextMenu` or `Qt::ActionsContextMenu`. `Prevent` eliminated the context menu and made right-click have no effect on the toolbar, while `Actions` made a nice context menu composed of the actions already in my toolbar. `Qt::NoContextMenu` didn't seem to have any effect.

`toolbar->setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::PreventContextMenu);`

Comment: This works, but you have to be aware that you're only preventing the context menu to appear for this one tool bar. If the user triggers the context menu anywhere else (like on another tool bar or a dock widget title bar), he will still be able to hide your "unhidable" tool bar.

Answer (score 17):

Use [setContextMenuPolicy (Qt::NoContextMenu)](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qwidget.html#contextMenuPolicy-prop) for the main window of the toolbar.

Comment: I mistyped and corrected it. NoContextMenu should be for the main window, not the toolbar.

Comment: Strange.. why does setting it on the QToolBar itself not work?

Comment: Interestingly, if you set `contextMenuPolicy` of the toolbar to `NoContextMenu`, the context menu still appears. **BUT** if you set it to `CustomContextMenu` and don't implement a custom context menu function, no context menu appears... strange.

Answer (score 14):

There are several ways to achieve this without having to alter the contextMenu functionality. See the following 3 PySide examples:

**1. Disable the `toggleViewAction` of the `QToolBar`**:

```
UnhidableToolBar = QToolBar()
UnhidableToolBar.toggleViewAction().setEnabled(False)
```

**2. Connect to the `visibilityChanged` signal**:

```
toolbar.visibilityChanged.connect(lambda: toolbar.setVisible(True))
```

**3. Subclass `QToolBar` and use the `hideEvent`**:

```
class UnhideableQToolBar(QToolBar):
    def hideEvent(self, event):
        self.setVisibile(True)
```

## Recommendation:

While 2 & 3 are pretty dirty, solution 1 shows the toolbar in the context menu like a `QDockWidget` that has the feature `DockWidgetClosable` set. So either use solution 1 or if you want to remove the action have a look at Steven's answer.

Answer (score 11):

Override QMainWindow::createPopupMenu() e.g.

```
QMenu* MyApp::createPopupMenu()
{
  QMenu* filteredMenu = QMainWindow::createPopupMenu();
  filteredMenu->removeAction( mUnhidableToolBar->toggleViewAction() );
  return filteredMenu;
}
```

Note that the other answers that suggest disabling the context menu will only work if you want to disable hiding/showing of *all* toolbars and *all* dock widgets.

Comment: Nice, clean answer.  Tip: You can avoid keeping track of all added toolbars by searching for `QToolbar` children in `createPopupMenu`.  Looking in direct children of the `QMainWindow` only seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing to do is:

```
self.toolbar.toggleViewAction().setVisible(False)
```

Unlike `self.toolbar.toggleViewAction().setEnabled(False)`, which still shows the disabled popup if you're right-clicking the toolbar for any reason.